# How to make iframe in vue application

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue application. In this application, another vue application should open in the iframe.I have a code:

```
<template>
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <button
     ...
    </button>
    <iframe
      :src="iframe.src"
      width="200"
      height="200"
      @load="iframeIsLoaded()"/>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
   ...
      data () {
        return {
          remoteAppUrl: '...',
          magentoRest: '...
          // iframe: {
          //   src: this.newUrl
          // }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        ...
          const newUrl = `${this.remoteAppUrl}${this.productId}?q=${this.magentoRest}`
         .
        },
        iframeIsLoaded () {
          this.iframeLoaded = true
        },

      }
```

in the iframe the current page opens, but  need to open the application that follows the link newUrl

Comment: Looks like you just need to make it `:src="magentoRest.iframe.src` (and uncomment)

Comment: Please, tell me how to close and open the iframe by clicking on the button

Comment: You would use [`v-if` or `v-show`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show) on the iframe, and use a click binding on the button to toggle the value. [This article](https://medium.com/@codebyjeff/vue-js-simple-tuts-toggling-b80edddee1ac) may help.